# Setting entityBaseURL on MetadataGeneratorFilter with Spring Security SAML and SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-saml

I am getting the following warning.  How do I set entityBaseURL?

```
2018-04-19 19:38:00.771  WARN 31852 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.s.m.MetadataGeneratorFilter        : Generated default entity base URL https://test-auth.onlinephotosubmission.com:443 based on values in the first server request. Please set property entityBaseURL on MetadataGenerator bean bean to fixate the value.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `application.properties`, add the following setting

```
saml.sso.metadata-generator.entity-base-url=https://myserver.mydomain.com
```

In your config file (mine is called `WebSecurityConfig`), add the following field

```
@Value("${saml.sso.metadata-generator.entity-base-url}")
private String entityBaseUrl;
```

Then in the same configuration file, set the `entityBaseUrl` on the `MetadataGenerator` bean by calling `setEntityBaseURL()`.

```
@Bean
public MetadataGenerator metadataGenerator() {

    MetadataGenerator metadataGenerator = new MetadataGenerator();
    metadataGenerator.setEntityId(samlSpId);
    metadataGenerator.setExtendedMetadata(extendedMetadata());
    metadataGenerator.setIncludeDiscoveryExtension(false);
    metadataGenerator.setKeyManager(keyManager());
    metadataGenerator.setEntityBaseURL(entityBaseUrl);
    return metadataGenerator;
}
```